# How to set environment variable in php lik .env file

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, environment-variables

How to include .env file in php. what are the configuration is required. Am hosted in aws ec2 instance and how to access env file in server. can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Linux EC2, if you can type 'env' command, it should list all the environment variables for you. Now if you want to include any specific environment variable before running your php script and if that variable is not part of your global variables listed in as part of 'env' command, you can always set that using export command. This can be set before running your php program or inside php startup script.

Sample command:
export env_variable_name="value"

For persistent environment variable, these are the common files where we need to specify:

/etc/environment

/etc/profile

example:
export PHP_HOME="/path/to/php/home"
export PATH=$PATH:$PHP_HOME/bin

if you are using Bash, you can declare the variables in the ~/.bashrc:
 $ export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"

To load the new environment variables into the current shell session use the source command:

$ source ~/.bashrc